# Perl6: check if STDIN has data

Tags: raku

In my Perl 6 script, I want to do a (preferably non-blocking) check of standard input to see if data is available. If this is the case, then I want to process it, otherwise I want to do other stuff.

Example (`consumer.p6`):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl6
use v6.b;
use fatal;
sub MAIN() returns UInt:D {
    while !$*IN.eof {
        if some_fancy_check_for_STDIN() { #TODO: this needs to be done.
            for $*IN.lines -> $line {
                say "Process '$line'";
            }
        }
        say "Do something Else.";
    }
    say "I'm done.";
    return 0;
}
```

As a STDIN-Generator I wrote another Perl6 script (`producer.p6`):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl6
use v6.b;
use fatal;

sub MAIN() returns UInt:D {
    $*OUT.say("aaaa aaa");
    sleep-until now+2;

    $*OUT.say("nbbasdf");
    sleep-until now+2;

    $*OUT.say("xxxxx");
    sleep-until now+2;

    return 0;
}
```

If `consumer.p6` works as expected, it should produce the following output, if called via `./producer.p6 | ./consumer.p6`:

```
Process 'aaaa aaa'
Do something Else.
Process 'nbbasdf'
Do something Else.
Process 'xxxxx'
Do something Else.
I'm done.
```

But actually, it produces the following output (if the `if` condition is commented out):

```
Process 'aaaa aaa'
Process 'nbbasdf'
Process 'xxxxx'
Do something Else.
I'm done.
```

Comment: See also [IO-select](https://github.com/tadzik/IO-Select) for non-blocking IO, though I was not able to install this module with `zef`...

Comment: You won't get much use out of IO-select, it uses parrot-internal classes, but rakudo on parrot has not been worked on in a long time now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using an old version of Perl 6, as `v6.b` is from before the official release of the language.
So some of what I have below may need a newer version to work.

Also why are you using `sleep-until now+2` instead of `sleep 2`?

---

One way to do this is to turn the `.lines` into a [Channel](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Channel), then you can use `.poll`.

```perl6
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.c;

sub MAIN () {
    # convert it into a Channel so we can poll it
    my $lines = $*IN.Supply.lines.Channel;

    my $running = True;
    $lines.closed.then: {$running = False}

    while $running {
        with $lines.poll() -> $line {
            say "Process '$line'";
        }
        say "Do something Else.";
        sleep ½;
    }
    say "I'm done.";
}
```

---

Note that the code above blocks at the `my $lines = …` line currently; so it doesn't start doing something until the first line comes in. To get around that you could do the following

```perl6
my $lines = supply {
    # unblock the $*IN.Supply.lines call
    whenever start $*IN.Supply {
        whenever .lines { .emit }
    }
}.Channel;
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach, this helped me a lot!