# is whenever signal() in react block order dependent?

Tags: raku

I have a small program which runs until a SIGINT is received or two lines (press enter twice) from stdin are received. The react block logic is:

```
react {
    whenever signal(SIGINT) {
        say "Got signal";
        exit;
    }
    whenever $*IN.lines.Supply {
        say "Got line";
        exit if $++ == 1 ;
    }
}
```

Program will exit on two entered lines as expected.

However CTRL-C will not do anything, unless it is followed by a line (enter).

If I switch the order of the whenever blocks, the program is interrupted by a SIGINT but doesn't execute the signal whenever block

```
react {
    whenever $*IN.lines.Supply {
        say "Got line";
        exit if $++ == 1 ;
    }
    whenever signal(SIGINT) {
        say "Got signal";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Is there some other setup required before using the signal sub? Is the order of whenever blocks important in a react block?

**Update**

So it seems the lines() call is blocking the react block from executing (thanks @Håkon). I kind of get it.

When comparing to a similar code structure for reading a socket I'm confused though. The presence of data (or lack of) has no effect on the signal handler executing and it can read lines just fine in this example:

```
my $listener=IO::Socket::Async.listen("0.0.0.0",4432);
react {
    whenever $listener {
        whenever $_.Supply.lines() {
            say "Got line";
        }
    }
    whenever signal(SIGINT) {
        say "Got signal";
        exit;
    }
}

#testing with:
#   curl http://localhost:4432
```

Why does this behave so different to my original code?

Comment: See also [Perl6: check if STDIN has data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49052801/2173773)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The order doesn't matter *provided the data sources really behave in an asynchronous manner*, which unfortunately is not the case here. The `Supply` coercer on a `Seq` does not introduce any concurrency, and does immediately try to produce a value to emit on the `Supply`, which in turn blocks on reading from `$*IN`. Thus, the second subscription doesn't have chance to be set up; the same underlying issue causes the other problems observed.

The solution is to force the reading to happen "elsewhere". We can do that with `Supply.from-list(...)`, plus telling it we really do want to use the current scheduler rather than its default `CurrentThreadScheduler`. Thus, this behaves as wanted:

```
react {
    whenever Supply.from-list($*IN.lines, scheduler => $*SCHEDULER) {
        say "Got line";
        exit if $++ == 1 ;
    }
    whenever signal(SIGINT) {
        say "Got signal";
        exit;
    }
}
```

It's likely this area will be revised somewhat in future Perl 6 versions. The current behavior was well-intended; the design principle was to avoid implicit introduction of concurrency, following the general principle that supplies are a tool for managing concurrency that inherently exists, rather than for introducing it. However, in reality, the lack of concurrency here has probably tripped up more folks than it has helped. (Further, we may look into offering real non-blocking file I/O, rather than building it from sync file I/O + threads.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! I have added a [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56251788/2173773) since it became too long for a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variant that runs the signal handler (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49055431/2173773) answer), but unfortunately autoflushing of `$*IN` seems to be turned off:

```
my $lines = supply {
    whenever start $*IN.lines.Supply {
        whenever .lines { .emit }
    }
}.Channel;

react {
    whenever signal(SIGINT) {
        say "Got signal";
        exit;
    }
    whenever $lines {
        say "Got line: '{$_}'";
        exit if $++ == 1;
    }
}
```

Now you have to press `CTRL-D` to print the lines, and then it print all lines entered as a concatenated string and after that `$*IN` is closed.. How can I turn on autoflushing for `$*IN` in this case?

Comment: Are you sure this is optimal? There's a whenever inside a whenever, you're using promises (with start)...

Comment: Thanks @Håkon, I've updated my question in response to your answer.