# What happens when different thread schedulers are used in the same react block?

Tags: asynchronous, raku

This is a follow up question to [is whenever signal() in react block order dependent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56232321/2173773)
.

The following code using the default scheduler [`$*SCHEDULER`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#index-entry-%24%2ASCHEDULER) lets the user exit immediately by pressing CTRL-C in the following event loop:

```
use v6;
my %scheduler;
my $use-default-scheduler = True;
if $use-default-scheduler {
    %scheduler = scheduler => $*SCHEDULER;
}    
react {
    whenever signal(SIGINT, |%scheduler) {
        say "Got signal";
        exit;
    }
    whenever Supply.from-list($*IN.lines, |%scheduler) {
        say "Got line";
        exit if $++ == 1 ;
    }
}
```

I am interested in what happens if I use two different thread schedulers in the same `react` loop? If I use the default thread scheduler of `Supply.from-list()` instead of `$*SCHEDULER`, by setting `$use-default-scheduler = False` in the above code. Now, the user cannot exit the `react` block immediately by pressing `CTRL-C`. If he presses `CTRL-C` the program simply hangs until enter is pressed.

So what actually happens here? Does the `react` focus on only one event loop at a time? (I here imagine two event loops, one for the default sceduler used in the first `whenever` for the SIGINT signal, and the other for the `$*IN.lines` supply). So the the `react` is now focusing on the `from-list()` scheduler for the `$*IN.lines` but somehow SIGINT has been ignored while in this event loop? So pressing `CTRL-C` does not change the state of the `react` block?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To see what actually happens, let's rewrite the program to (sort-of) cover what `react` does. I'm going to ignore numerous details that don't matter too much to the question at hand.

To keep things a bit more compact, I'll just rewrite this segment of the provided program:

```
react {
    whenever signal(SIGINT, |%scheduler) {
        say "Got signal";
        exit;
    }
    whenever Supply.from-list($*IN.lines, |%scheduler) {
        say "Got line";
        exit if $++ == 1 ;
    }
}
```

First of all, a `react { ... }` is really just like `await supply { ... }` - that is, it taps the `supply { }` block and `await`s its end.

```
await supply {
    whenever signal(SIGINT, |%scheduler) {
        say "Got signal";
        exit;
    }
    whenever Supply.from-list($*IN.lines, |%scheduler) {
        say "Got line";
        exit if $++ == 1 ;
    }
}
```

But what is a `supply` block? At its heart, `supply` (and so `react`) offer:

- Concurrency control, so it will process one message at a time (thus we need some kind of lock; it uses `Lock::Async` for this)
- Completion and error propagation (in a blatant bit of cheating, we'll use a `Promise` to implement this, because we only really want the `react` part; the real thing produces a resulting `Supply` that we can `emit` values into)
- Completing automatically when there are no outstanding subscriptions (we'll track those in an `SetHash`)

Thus, we could rewrite the program as something like this:

```
await do {
    # Concurency control
    my $lock = Lock::Async.new;
    # Completion/error conveyance
    my $done = Promise.new;
    # What's active?
    my %active is SetHash;

    # An implementation a bit like that behind the `whenever` keyword, but with
    # plenty of things that don't matter for this question missing.
    sub whenever-impl(Supply $s, &block) {
        # Tap the Supply
        my $tap;
        $s.tap:
            # When it gets tapped, add the tap to our active set.
            tap => {
                $tap = $_; 
                %active{$_} = True;
            },
            # Run the handler for any events
            { $lock.protect: { block($_) } },
            # When this one is done, remove it from the %active list; if it's
            # the last thing, we're done overall.
            done => {
                $lock.protect: {
                    %active{$tap}:delete;
                    $done.keep() unless %active;
                }
            },
            # If there's an async error, close all taps and pass it along.
            quit => {
                $lock.protect: -> $err {
                    .close for %active.keys;
                    $done.quit($err);
                }
            }
    }

    # We hold the lock while doing initial setup, so you can rely on having
    # done all initialization before processing a first message.
    $lock.protect: {
        whenever-impl signal(SIGINT, |%scheduler), {
            say "Got signal";
            exit;
        }
        whenever-impl Supply.from-list($*IN.lines, |%scheduler), {
            say "Got line";
            exit if $++ == 1 ;
        }
    }

    $done
}
```

Notice that there's nothing whatsoever about schedulers or event loops in here; a `supply` or `react` doesn't care about who a message comes from, it just cares about its own integrity, enforced through the `Lock::Async`. Also notice that it doesn't introduce any concurrency either: it really is just a concurrency control construct.

Typically, one uses `supply` and `react` with data sources where you `tap` them and immediately get back control. We then proceed through to set up further `whenever` blocks, fall out of the setup phase, and the lock is available for any messages we receive. This behavior is what you get with just about all supplies that you usually encounter. It's the case with `signal(...)`. It's also the case when you give `Supply.from-list(...)` an explicit scheduler, passing in `$*SCHEDULER`; in such a case, it schedules the loop that reads from `$*IN` on the pool and immediately hands back control.

The problem comes when we encounter something that does *not* behave like that. If we tap `Supply.from-list($*IN.lines)`, it defaults to doing the read from `$*IN` on the current thread to produce a value to `emit`, because `Supply.from-list` uses `CurrentThreadScheduler` as its default. And what does that do? Just run the code it's asked to run immediately!

This leaves us with one more mystery, however. Given `Lock::Async` is not reentrant, then if we:

1. Acquire the lock to do setup
2. Call `tap` on the `Supply.from-list(...)`, which runs synchronously and tries to `emit` a value
3. Try to acquire the lock so we can process the value

Then we'd just get a deadlock, because we're trying to acquire a non-reentrant lock that is already held - by us. Indeed, if you run my desugar of the program here, that is precisely what happens: it hangs. However, the original code does not hang; it just behaves a bit awkwardly. What gives?

One of the things the real implementation does is detect such cases during the setup phase; it then takes a continuation, and resumes it after the setup phase is completed. This means we can do things like:

```
my $primes = supply {
    .emit for ^Inf .grep(*.is-prime);
}
react {
    whenever $primes { .say }
    whenever Promise.in(3) { done }
}
```

And have it work out. I won't reproduce *that* fun here, but it should be possible with sufficiently cunning use of `gather`/`take`.

Comment: I suspect it wouldn't be good use of jnthn's time to respond to this comment, but if anyone reads the last sentence of his answer ("sufficiently cunning use of `gather`/`take`"), please note a Raku doc issue recently filed by niner: ["`gather`/`take` must not be used to collect results from `react`/`whenever`"](https://github.com/Raku/doc/issues/4041).